# output of grep like "file:ln#:matchedpattern:paragraph" possible?

Tags: grep

I use the following command to my liking, but perfection is better;-)

```
grep -w -i -r -n -f all.txt . > output.txt  

./index.php:86:complete paragraph1
./index.php:89:complete paragraph2
```

With this:

```
grep -w -i -r -o -n -f all.txt . > output.txt
```

We get :

```
./index.php:86:match1
./index.php:89:match2
```

Is it also possible to get a combination of that? Like this:

```
./index.php:86:match1:complete paragraph1
./index.php:89:match2:complete paragraph2
```

Would be great, still better than that would be even a part ofthe paragraph, but i guess that is a little much to ask for with such a simple tool;-)

Thanks!

Comment: Please define "part of .the paragraph"

Comment: String: "lion", Paragraph: "the jungleisfilledwith animals but the lion isnotoneof them", Part of: ... filled with animals but the lion is not ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` doesn't have a facility for this, but it's easy to reimplement the useful parts in a simple Awk script.

```
awk 'NR==FNR { p[++i] = tolower($0); next }
    { line = tolower($0); for (j=1; j<=i; ++j) if (match(line, p[j]))
        { printf "%s:%i:%s:%s\n", FILENAME, FNR, substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH), $0;
          next } }' all.txt files...
```

The `NR==FNR` condition matches on the first input file.  Each line in that file is converted to lowercase and read into the array `p`.

The second action only applies to the second and subsequent files.  It loops over the items in `p` and checks whether the current line matches.  If so, a match message is printed, and we skip to the next input line.

Comment: I am not familiar with AWK at all, so i'd have to read into it to at least know what i will be doing to the server.
Before i accept it as an answer, that's the least i can do;-)

Comment: Updated with a brief explanation.

Comment: still struggling. What if i need it to search in curl'd pages (so it basicly loops twice: 1 for URLs, 1 for strings),like this? curl -s $url | awk .... What do i do with the txtfile containing the strings? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Sounds like a significant enough extension that you could post a new question to properly explain what you need, anyway.  Linking back to this question for background would probably be a good idea.  But if I understand at all what you mean, have Awk read standard input and a text file, like `curl ... | awk '...' all.txt -` where `-` means, read standard input.

Comment: Almost perfect. The only issue now is that the last '-' prints '-' as the FILENAME as well. We can remove it from the PRINT since we already echo the cURL, but ifthere's an easy fix, we'duse that. Cheers.

Comment: `(FILENAME=="-"?:"":FILENAME)` evaluates to an empty string if the filename is a dash, and to the filename otherwise.